# Why does node's path.resolve allow but ignore multiple root paths?

Tags: node.js

According to the [Node.js docs](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/path.html#path_path_resolve_paths), `path.resolve` has the following behavior:

> The given sequence of paths is processed from right to left, with each
>   subsequent path prepended until an absolute path is constructed. For
>   instance, given the sequence of path segments: /foo, /bar, baz,
>   calling `path.resolve('/foo', '/bar', 'baz')` would return `/bar/baz`

It doesn't explain WHY, however. I would expect this to either:

- throw an error about multiple absolute path elements, or
- return `/foo/bar/baz`

What is the purpose of this behavior? In what kind of scenarios would this be useful?

EDIT: To clarify, I understand the purpose of `path.resolve` in general is to create an absolute path out of a series of path elements. E.g.

```
path.resolve('/foo', 'baz')               // '/foo/baz'
path.resolve('/foo', 'bar', '..', 'baz')  // '/foo/baz'
path.resolve('bar', 'baz')                // '/current/working/dir/bar/baz'
```

This differs from `path.join`, which makes no guarantee that the result is an absolute path, but rather just ensures that the elements have the proper path separator between them.

```
path.join('bar', 'baz')                   // 'bar/baz'
```

I just can't imagine the purpose of silently allowing superfluous args at the beginning of resolve, though, such as:

```
path.resolve('/completely', 'useless', '/arguments', '/bar', 'baz') // '/bar/baz
```

Comment: Imagine the first segment is the absolute path of a file, and the second segment represents the path in an `import` statement within that file, which just happens to be another absolute path, then the third segment represents a relative path (with the leading `./` removed) in an `import` statement within the second file. The resolved path represents the absolute path of the third file.

Comment: I think you're confusing `path.join()` and `path.resolve()`. `path.join('/foo', '/bar', 'baz')` would return `/foo/bar/baz`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A reasonable use for this would be to allow a user to input a path that could either be absolute or relative to a predefined location. The signature could be something like:

```
const createPath = (defaultBasePath = process.cwd(), userInput) => {
  return path.resolve(defaultBasePath, userInput)
}
```

IMO it's trying to solve too many cases with varargs. There are an infinite number of nonsensical options, but it does allow for flexibility of use...

Answer (score 0):

**How**

The purpose of `path.resolve(...)` is to construct the absolute path given a set of paths/path segments as parameters.
Absolute path means,

> An absolute pathname, also referred to as an absolute path or a full path, is the location of a filesystem object (i.e., file, directory or link) relative to the root directory where the root directory is '/'. Eg. /usr/bin/node

So, taking the example from your question,

```
path.resolve('/foo', '/bar', 'baz')
```

Step-1:
First parameter `'baz'` is taken and it is noted that it isn't an absolute path.

Step-2:
`'/bar'` is the next parameter and it is prepended giving `/bar/baz`. This is an absolute path as described in the definition above.

Now that we have resolved and got our absolute path we can ignore the other parameters present and return `/bar/baz`

**Note**:

- As mentioned in the docs if after going through all the parameters if no absolute path is formed then the current working directory is used
  Example:

```
// Current working directory: /Users/ramanur/my-app
console.log('Absolute path', path.resolve('package.json')); // /Users/ramanur/my-app/package.json
```

- Also as mentioned in the docs the resulting path is normalized and trailing slashes are removed unless the path is resolved to the root directory

**Why**

Why does it do this? If you wanted it to return `/foo/bar/baz` then you would have used `path.join(...)`.

This is kind of like `path.normalize(...)`, given a set of paths/path segments it tries to "normalize" and return an acceptable absolute path.

**Scenarios**

Let me give a vague example from the top of my head.
Suppose if a function wants to read from a file but it needs to know the path to that file.
You could use `path.resolve(...)` and pass the absolute path to the function.

Example:`readFile(path.resolve("results.txt"))`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I expanded a bit above in the EDIT: section. I get the "normal" cases for `resolve`. I'm just not clear on the purpose of the short-circuit behavior, which is essentially "check and see if any of the middle parts are absolute and, if so, discard all prior args".